# Arithmetic doubt while studying limits of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, arithmetic, fractions

While studying limits of sequences, I came across these expressions.

$\left|\frac{-5}{n+2}\right|<\delta \iff\frac{5}{n+2}<\delta \iff n+2>\frac{1}{\delta }$

$n\in \mathbb N$

$\delta\in \mathbb R$ and $\delta >0$

I'm struggling to understand how it went from the second expression ($\frac{5}{n+2}<\delta$) to the third ($n+2>\frac{1}{\delta }$)

Comment: As written at this moment, the expressions are not equivalent. Did you accidentally omit or insert a factor of $5$? If both inequalities are accurately copied, it may pay to edit the question to show the exact words that say how the formulas are supposed to be related.

Comment: Change the equal-to signs to implication sign $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: The use of "$=$" between supposedly equivalent statements is odd and confusing (I don't know whether you or your source did that). Writing "if and only if" is better. In fact in this case all the implications to the right are correct, since $1 < 5$.

Comment: Are you sure the book used equivalence ($\iff$) rather than implies ($\implies$).  That seems a severe error.  Or is it possible that the $1$ was a typo and the book meant $5$?  What does it figure in context.  (I assume this is part of some delta epsilon proof.. perhaps to prove $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {-5}{x+2} = 0$?)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I think it shouldn't be an = because that's the confusing bit, it should should be an implication sign.

If that is the case then,

$\lvert\frac{−5}{n+2}\rvert< δ => \frac{5}{n+2} < δ => 5 < δ(n+2)$ 
$=> \frac{5}{δ} < n+2$

Since $\frac{1}{δ} < \frac{5}{δ}, => \frac{1}{δ} < n+2$

This is assuming that $n+2 > 0$ and $δ > 0$.
Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Can't be equivalence because $\frac 1\delta < n+2 \iff \frac 5\delta < n+2$ is not true.

Comment: Yup, you are correct! It's also why I used the implication sign, but thanks! Have removed that so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you! Already edited the question!

Comment: Hi Daniel! Like fleablood has pointed out, that equivalence simply isn't true both ways for all $n$. Unless we're talking about some specific $n$ for which this holds, for example for $3 ≤ n$ it's true such that $δ > 1$. Could you maybe give us more context?

Answer (score 1):

I guess we are assuming $n$ is positive, and as stated in the comments, this is probably a good place to use the implication sign, meaning that 
$$\frac{5}{n+2}<\delta\quad  \text{implies, or } \implies n+2>\frac{1}{\delta}$$
And this is because we can take the reciprocal of each side of your second inequality (and remember to flip the direction!) to get
$$\frac{n+2}{5}>\frac{1}{\delta}$$
And for positive $x$, we have $x>y \implies x+4x > y \implies5x>y $ so we have
$$n+2>\frac{1}{\delta}$$

Answer (score 0):

To treat that as an equal sign just makes it dead wrong.  What they mean is implies the next.   (Actually; we must assume $\delta > 0$ and that $n + 2 > 0$.  I presume those are conditions stated in the source that you omitted?  That $n\in \mathbb N$?)

(Note: these implications only work one way.)

$\left|\frac{-5}{n+2}\right|<\delta \implies\frac{5}{n+2}<\delta \implies n+2>\frac{1}{\delta }$

$|\frac {-5}{n+2}| < \delta \implies \frac {5}{n+2} < \delta$.

That should be clear $|\frac {-5}{n+2}|= \frac {5}{n+2}$ (if $n+2 > 0$).  We could make the stronger.  $|\frac {-5}{n+2}| < \delta \iff \frac {5}{n+2} < \delta$.

Now...

$\frac{5}{n+2}<\delta \implies n+2>\frac{1}{\delta }$

This is presumably the part you have trouble with.

$\frac{5}{n+2}<\delta \iff$

$\frac{5}{n+2}\frac{n+2}{\delta} < \delta \frac{n+2}{\delta}\iff$ (assuming $n+2 > 0; \delta > 0$)

$\frac 5{\delta} < n+2$

So $\left|\frac{-5}{n+2}\right|<\delta \iff\frac{5}{n+2}<\delta \iff n+2>\frac{5}{\delta }$

Now $\frac 1{\delta} < \frac 5{\delta}$ so

$\frac 1{\delta} < \frac 5{\delta}< n+2$.

So $\frac {5}{n+2} \le \delta \implies n+2 > \frac 1{\delta}$

But obviously that is only one way.  $n+2 > \frac 1{\delta} \implies (\frac 1{n+2} < \delta; \frac 1{\delta} < \frac 5{\delta}) \not \implies \frac {5}{n+2} < \delta$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to refer to them more easily, let’s label the inequalities as follows:

a) $\left\lvert\frac{-5}{n+2}\right\rvert < \delta$

b) $\frac{5}{n+2} < \delta$

c) $n+2>\frac 1\delta$

The fact that $n\in\mathbb N$ implies that $n+2>0$, in which case 
$\left\lvert\frac{-5}{n+2}\right\rvert = \frac{5}{n+2}$
and therefore a) and b) actually are equivalent.

Again, since $n+2>0$ and $\delta>0,$ then 
$\frac{n+2}{\delta}>0$
and we can multiply both sides of b) by 
$\frac{n+2}{\delta} $ 
while preserving the direction of the $<$ sign.
The result is
$\frac{5}{\delta}<n+2.$
Now just turn that around:
$$ n+2 > \frac{5}{\delta}.$$
The inequality above is exactly equivalent to b), since we have just derived it from b) and can multiply it by 
$\frac{\delta}{n+2}$ to get b) again.

It should be obvious enough that 
$\frac 5\delta > \frac 1\delta,$
and therefore b) implies c).

But consider the case $n=1,$ $\delta=1.$ In that case c) is true but b) is false. 
Therefore the two statements are *not* equivalent, and if your book says they are it is an error.